# php string variable with xml data

Tags: php, xml, parsing

simply i have a string variable which contains some xml data :

```
$temp = '<chart manageResize="1" dateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy" ganttLineColor="CCCCCC" ganttLineAlpha="20" gridBorderAlpha="20" showTaskNames="1" hoverCapBgColor="F1F1F1" hoverCapBorderColor="333333" paletteThemeColor="333333" hoverBandColor="3d3d3d" hoverBandAlpha="95" showGanttPaneHorizontalHoverBand="0" showGanttPaneVerticalHoverBand="0">\n\
<categories bgColor="333333"  baseFont="Arial" baseFontCOlor="FFFFFF" baseFontSize="12" showhoverband="0" >\n\
    <category start="1/1/2005" end="31/5/2005" align="center" name="Sales Territory Assignment" fontColor="ffffff" isBold="1" fontSize="16" />\n\
</categories>\n\
<categories font="Arial" fontColor="ffffff" isBold="1" fontSize="12" bgColor="333333">\n\
    <category start="1/1/2005" end="31/1/2005" name="January" />\n\
    <category start="1/2/2005" end="28/2/2005" name="February" />\n\
    <category start="1/3/2005" end="31/3/2005" name="March" />\n\
    <category start="1/4/2005" end="30/4/2005" name="April"/>\n\
    <category start="1/5/2005" end="31/5/2005" name="May" />\n\
</categories>\n\
<processes headerbgColor="333333" fontColor="ffffff" fontSize="12" bgColor="333333" align="right" >\n\
    <process Name="Tom" id="1" />\n\
    <process Name="Harry" id="2" />\n\
    <process Name="Mary" id="4" />\n\
    <process Name="Mike" id="3" />\n\
</processes>\n\
<tasks  color="" alpha="" font="" fontColor="" fontSize="" isAnimated="1">\n\
    <task name="North" processId="1" start="3/1/2005" end="4/2/2005" Id="1_1" color="e1f5ff" borderColor="AFD8F8"/>\n\
    <task name="East" processId="1" start="6/2/2005" end="24/3/2005" Id="1_2" color="e1f5ff" borderColor="AFD8F8"/>\n\
    <task name="Vacation" processId="1" start="25/3/2005" end="18/4/2005" Id="1_3" color="e1f5ff" borderColor="AFD8F8" height="2" showBorder="1" topPadding="49%"/>\n\
    <task name="South" processId="1" start="18/4/2005" end="24/5/2005" Id="1_4" color="e1f5ff" borderColor="AFD8F8"/>\n\
    <task name="South" processId="2" start="15/1/2005" end="5/3/2005" Id="2_1" color="F6BD0F" borderColor="F6BD0F"/>\n\
    <task name="West" processId="2" start="21/3/2005" end="10/5/2005" Id="2_2" color="F6BD0F" borderColor="F6BD0F"/>\n\
    <task name="Global" processId="3" start="7/1/2005" end="26/5/2005" Id="3_1" width="12" color="8BBA00" borderColor="8BBA00"/>\n\
    <task name="South" processId="4" start="13/3/2005" end="19/4/2005" Id="4_1" width="12" color="FF654F" borderColor="FF654F" />\n\
</tasks>\n\
\n\
</chart>';
```

then when i try to echo my variable with simple (echo) i get :

> \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\
>   \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\

when i print using :

```
echo nl2br(htmlentities($temp));
```

then i get all the data correctly 
now , i'm trying to pass this variable into java script as follows:

```
var php_var = "<?php echo $temp; ?>";
```

but here the passed value will be :

> \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\
>   \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\

any idea to pass the real data?

Comment: you can use [SimpleXML](http://us1.php.net/simplexml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_encode to safely rewrite a PHP-string (or array/object) to javascript:

```
<script>
    var php_var = <?php echo json_encode($temp); ?>
</script>
```

json_encode will place the starting and ending '

Besides that: don't use \n in a PHP-string which you open with a single-quote, that only works with double-quotes (").